# Why there is a different number of users in two Linux-PC's?

Tags: terminal, linux-mint, users

I have two laptops. The first is a 'Linux-Mint-Mate-desktop'. The second is 'Peppermint-LXDE-desktop'.

When I open the terminal on the 'Linux-Mint-Mate-desktop-PC' and run the 'who' command, or some other command that is showing the number of
logged-in users in the system, I see 2 logged-in users.

```
~ $ who
xxx   tty8         2021-10-24 20:46 (:0)
xxx   pts/0        2021-10-26 15:38 (:0.0)
```

When I open the terminal on the 'Peppermint-LXDE-desktop-PC' and run the 'who' command, or some other command that is showing the number of
logged-in users in the system, I see just 1 logged-in user.

```
~ $ who
zzz   tty7         2021-10-24 20:46 (:0)
```

part of env output 'Linux-Mint-Mate-desktop-PC':

```
... DESKTOP_SESSION=mate      ...
... XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=MATE  ...
```

part of env output 'Peppermint-LXDE-desktop-PC'

```
... DESKTOP_SESSION=Peppermint ... 
... XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=LXDE   ...
```

In both cases I am the only user. Why the difference?

Comment: It shows who is logged into which terminal. If a user is logged into more than one terminal on the same host, you see several entries. It seems that in the first case, the system uses a tty for communicating with you, and a pseudoterminal. In the second case, the pseudoterminal is missing. The question seems to boild down to "why is it that LXDE does not need to set up a pseudoterminal?".

Comment: See also [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335992/what-is-the-difference-between-pts-and-tty-and-0#335994), in particularily the accepted answer, which shows how pseudoterminal come into play in an X server.